# What are the memory management checks that XCode does?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

What are the memory management checks that XCode does ?

Comment: this was jus one of the questions that my friend got for an interview...but i guess XCode does'nt do any such check....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xcode specifically doesn't do any, it just compiles your code as far as i'm aware.

You can use a performance tool called 'Leaks' to check for memory leaks, this is a program that is kind of part of xcode.

Comment: just as i thought...was just curious ...as one of my friends was asked such a question...

Answer (score 0):

The question is referring to the static analyzer, that you can run using the 'Build and Analyze' (Xcode 3) or 'Analyze' (Xcode 4) menus.